# In JavaScript is it possible to add to a callback function instead of overwriting it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know if I'm saying this right, so I'll just ask by explaining with an example.

Let's say I've written a jQuery plugin with an `onShowEdit` callback.

I later use my plugin and add a bunch of other default functions/methods to the event:

```
$('.editable_module:not(.custom)').editable({
   onShowEdit: function(el){
      initRequired();
      $(':radio, :checkbox', el).prettyCheckboxes();
      initDatePickers();
      initChosen();
      initMaskedInputs();
      $('.dynamic_box.tabs').dynamicBoxTabs();
      $('.trigger_dynamic_box').triggerDynamicBox('true');
   }
});
```

So now I have a basic/default element (`.editable_module`) that calls the plugin and has some methods/functions that are going to be used in all instances.

My question comes when I have a need to add something to this for a 'one time' kind of deal (I need to add some behavior to this callback/event but not something that is used normally). Is it possible to extend or add to this callback/event without overwriting it? I mean, I know I can go in and do this:

```
$('#new_selector').editable({
   onShowEdit: function(el){
      initRequired();
      $(':radio, :checkbox', el).prettyCheckboxes();
      initDatePickers();
      initChosen();
      initMaskedInputs();
      $('.dynamic_box.tabs').dynamicBoxTabs();
      $('.trigger_dynamic_box').triggerDynamicBox('true');

      //ADD SOME NEW STUFF HERE
   }
});
```

But is that really my only option?

Thanks in advance for any input/suggestions.

Comment: You can create a event-based plugin system, to allow multiple "callbacks" to be run (and/or removed).

Comment: So, something like 'onShowEdit' and `onShowEdit2' (probably a better name, haha). Where both are called at the same time?

Comment: As shown in pimvdbs answer. You can also namespace events, so to distinguish the events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could consider jQuery's own event system as follows: http://jsfiddle.net/VQqXM/1/. You can integrate this in your `$.fn` function pretty easily - just pass the appropriate function as property of the object instead of a function literal.

```
$("input").on("foo", function() {
    alert(1);
});

// later

$("input").on("foo", function() {
    alert(2);
});

// later

$("input").trigger("foo"); // alerts 1 and 2
```

You can simply use `.on`/`.off` to bind and unbind events, and trigger them all with `.trigger`. jQuery also supports [namespacing](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events) of the event names to make sure you're not using an already used event.

Comment: This was the route I was thinking was plausible. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could use the new `$.Callbacks()` method

```
var $onShowEditCBObj = $.Callbacks();
function onShowEditHandler() {
  $onShowEditCBObj.fire();
}
$('#new_selector').editable({
   onShowEdit: onShowEditHandler
});
// add default event to callbacks obj
$onShowEditCBObj.add(function(){
  initRequired();
  $(':radio, :checkbox', el).prettyCheckboxes();
  initDatePickers();
  initChosen();
  initMaskedInputs();
  $('.dynamic_box.tabs').dynamicBoxTabs();
  $('.trigger_dynamic_box').triggerDynamicBox('true');
});
// add a one time method to the callbacks obj
function oneTimeEvent () {
  alert("worky");
  $onShowEditCBObj.remove(oneTimeEvent);
}
$onShowEditCBObj.add(oneTimeEvent)
```

With this setup, you can change what callbacks will be fired without having to do anything extra to the editable plugin.

Edit: I didn't realize that you wrote the plugin. With that in mind, pimvdb's answer is more robust than requiring the developer to code a certain way.

Comment: Well I've actually been curious about this on a number of occasions, including some where I didn't write the plugin, so I this is still really helpful! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, the key word here is "factory".

jQuery is itself a factory but to get what you describe, you need your plugin also to be a factory within the factory. That requires the plugin to be written in a certain way.

Probably the easiest approach is to use jQuery's UI widget factory. [Read about it here](http://blog.petersendidit.com/post/stateful-jquery-plugins-with-jquery-uis-widget-factory/).

Answer (score 0):

Defining a separate function for onShowEdit should work.

```
var myOnShowEdit = function(el, extra_fn) {
    //standard functionality goes here
    if (typeof extra_fn==='function') extra_fn(); //support for extra stuff
}
$('.editable_module:not(.custom)').editable({
    onShowEdit: function(el) {
        myOnShowEdit(el);
    }
});
$('#new_selector').editable({
    onShowEdit: function(el) {
        myOnShowEdit(el, function(){console.log('hi');});
    }
});
```

This will give you fair flexibility to add whatever functionality you need in addition to the standard stuff. Just be aware of how `this` may shift contexts.